# In Delphi, and why are not directly comparable threadvar types of floating point?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, floating-point, double

I've tested this in Delphi 6,7 and XE2, all show this error.
I would like to directly compare two floating-point numbers in the thread,like this:

```
threadvar
  a,b : Double;

procedure test;
begin
  if a > b  then
    ;
end;
```

but when compiling, DCC occurred an internal error.So i changed it like this:

```
threadvar
  a,b : Double;

procedure test;
begin
  if a - b > 0  then
    ;
end;
```

the error disappeared,why?

Comment: An "internal error" in the Delphi compiler is generally not something that should happen. In other words, this is most likely a bug that someone from Embarcadero would need to address rather than a programming question that someone on StackOverflow could "answer".

Comment: So if I copy directly your first block of code and put it into a unit as is, I'' get an internal error? Could it be because you're not intializing a or b before they're used in `procedure test`?

Comment: You did not mention the version of Delphi you are using; however I was able to reproduce this in Delphi 2010. The exact error I received was this: [DCC Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(36): F2084 Internal Error: URW2306

Comment: I used Delphi 6, 7 and XE2 to compile this code, all have an internal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly a bug in the compiler. I have reported the bug to Quality Central, [QC#101656](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101656). The bug only affects the 32 bit compiler, not that that will be of much consolation to anyone!

You can work around it by putting your variables in a record like this:

```
threadvar
  r: record
    a,b: Double;
  end;

procedure test;
begin
  if r.a > r.b then
    ;
end;
```

Comment: Another workaround (not necessarily better) seems to be to indirectly refer to the values: `if PDouble(@a)^ > PDouble(@b)^ then`

Comment: I'd guess using the CompareValue routine from Math unit would fix the issue too... And it's usually the prefered method for comparing float value to start with.

Comment: @Ken CompareValue also sidesteps the internal error, but I don't agree that it is to be preferred to the inequality operators.